# MongoDB WiredTiger error: WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: operation not permitted

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

MongoDB was working beautifully for me for several months until I had an unexpected shutdown a week or two ago. Since then, I've been getting the error in the title that snowballs into an invalid argument, then a library panic, then some fatal assertions which cause MongoDB to crash.

Now, I've done my research: the normal answers are to run the repair function and to make sure SELinux isn't screwing up the process. Neither of those have worked. The error gets thrown during WiredTiger's checkpoint process, so reads/writes to the database aren't the issue, and because it's during the checkpoint process, it guarantees that MongoDB won't stay up for more than a day.

To be clear: all the files in the database are owned by mongod:mongod, have permissions set to 600 (default, and I tried setting them to 755 to see if that fixed it, and it didn't). I'm running mongodb as a service on a CentOS 7 box, and the service file specifies that it should run as user mongod. The mongod.conf file specifies a mounted filesystem as the database, and it was happy with that until the unexpected shutdown. I'm running MongoDB version 4.0.1, so WiredTiger really doesn't like it if I disable Journaling either (disregarding the fact that I shouldn't disable it in the first place).

I feel like I've exhausted all my options, and that the only thing I can do is backup my data and reinstall MongoDB. Are there any that I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

After creating a backup of my data via mongodump, shutting down mongo, removing the entire database with rm -rf 'path-to-database', rebooting mongo (without the replication config), and restoring the data with mongorestore, mongodb still crashes. This time, however, it's with an Invariant failure after the open: operation not permitted. The only conclusion I can think of is that the data itself has become corrupted in some way. Thankfully, this isn't "mission critical" data, so to speak, and I can easily obtain new data.

Unfortunately, this doesn't answer my original question of "what other options do I have?". However, I'm still posting this in case others run into this same kind of issue.

EDIT: invariant issue was caused by me forgetting to re-initialize my replication set. After fixing that, it's clean. Because of this, I no longer believe it was a data corruption issue, but a checkpoint corruption issue.

EDIT 2: So the issue arose again after about a week, and after another week of trying various debugging methods, I tried simply moving the mongo process to another server. So far, that's been working. The previous server was acting up (I couldn't even run top at one point - another process had a lock on a necessary library file to run it), so here's to hoping that the current server doesn't follow suite.